# Is it possible to implement scrollbar in Jframe without Jpanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I've written a long code involving several frames using only JFrame, and now I need a scrollbar for one of the frames. It seems like the only way to use JScrollPane is with JPanel, but I dont want to rewrite everything, is there a way?

```
       frames[2] = new JFrame("Title");
   frames[2].setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);//EXIT_ON_CLOSE
   frames[2].setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/Users/mac/Downloads/bg.000.jpg")));
   frames[2].setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   frames[2].setLayout(new FlowLayout());
   frames[2].setResizable(true);
   frames[2].setSize(750,433);
   label[4] = new JLabel (" Search : ", JLabel.CENTER);
   label[4].setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 16));
   label[4].setForeground(Color.BLACK);// font color
   frames[2].add(label[4]);
   TextField[2]= new JTextField ("Enter name", 15);
   TextField[2].setFont(font);
   frames[2].add(TextField[2]);
```

This is the frame (frame[2]) that I would like the scrollbar to be used in.

Comment: That's because you should only have _one_ `JFrame` - that is the root window. Your approach is broken so the answer is not easily.

Comment: "I dont want to rewrite everything" You don't have to. Maybe you should, because these components in arrays are weird, but you don't have to. Just put the label & textfield in the panel in the scrollpane and that's it. From what you've shown, I'm uncertain why you think it's a problem.